Phase Angle Firing Control of TRIAC
I am using an Arduino to control an incandescent light bulb using TRIAC. I have the following setup:
AC Input - 20VAC @60Hz using a stepped down transformer.
DC - Diode Rectifier.
The output of the diode rectifier is sent to an optocoupler (4N25) through current limiting resistors (two 1.5 kΩ in parallel rated at 2W - using such high resistance and wattage because a lower valued one seemed to overheat and burn). The output of the optocoupler is sent to the digital pin of the Arduino. A potentiometer is used to generate the firing angle reference. The output of the Arduino is sent to MOC3020 TRIAC driver to fire the TRIAC.
The problem I am having right now is that the zero crossings are not aligning (there is a phase-shift) with the AC sine wave as you can see in the attached snapshot. I double checked my ground references and all the connections, I changed the diode rectifier, 4N25 optocoupler, and resistors. Nothing seems to fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.
Attached is a very similar circuit schematic to the one I am using.



Please draw a schematic of the circuit you describe.

You are overdriving the LED and collector pull up is current is too high. Raise both R's to get a narrow pulse. Phase is too early.

@Vir I have attached the schematic

Oh is it? Could you please explain how I am overdriving the LED?

Sure after you post the opto link but LED should be around 20 to 50 mW or less , output should be much less

This is the optocoupler I am using - https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf

https://tinyurl.com/2c2oyotg or https://tinyurl.com/24n3fzqj

“Very similar“ is not good enough. What is the exact schematic? Include the Arduino power supply and probe connections and trace numbers. And please include an oscilloscope digital image, rather than a photo of the screen. That’s a fancy scope, I’m sure it can produce a proper image.
